# why it get old dataset

Tags: c#

My program is working normally when I select a listbox item.it getting datas correct dataset and correctly.when I write  to textbox,my source method working and finding right results.but after when I selected listbox item it bringing old dataset datas to screen.What can I do in this methods?

```
public void ara(string str, int neyegore)
{
      sqlcon.Open();
      if (neyegore == 0)
          komut = new SqlCommand("select * from FilmTablo WHERE ad LIKE '%" + str + "%'", sqlcon);
      else if (neyegore == 1)
          komut = new SqlCommand("select * from FilmTablo WHERE tur LIKE '%" + str + "%'", sqlcon);
      else if (neyegore == 2)
          komut = new SqlCommand("select * from FilmTablo WHERE yonetmen LIKE '%" + str + "%'", sqlcon);
      else if (neyegore == 3)
          komut = new SqlCommand("select * from FilmTablo WHERE oyuncular LIKE '%" + str + "%'", sqlcon);

      sdr = null;
      sdr = komut.ExecuteReader();
      dt2 = new DataTable();
      dt2.Load(sdr);
      ds2 = new DataSet();
      ds2.Tables.Add(dt2);
      listBox1.Items.Clear();
      // sayac2 = 1;
      int i = 0;

      while (i < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
      {
         listBox1.Items.Add(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
         i++;
      }
      sqlcon.Close();
     }



private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{                  
                txtad.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim();
                txttur.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString().Trim();
                txtsure.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[2].ToString().Trim();
                txtyonetmen.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim();
                txtoyuncular.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[4].ToString().Trim();
                txtsenaryo.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[5].ToString().Trim();
                byte[] resim = (byte[])ds.Tables[1].Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[7];
                image1.Source = GetBitmapImage(resim);
 }


public void listeyiguncelle()
{
            sqlcon.Open();
            komut = new SqlCommand("select * from FilmTablo", sqlcon);
            sdr = null;
            sdr = komut.ExecuteReader();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sdr);
            ds = new FilmDataDataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            int i = 0;
            //MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count.ToString());
            while (i < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[1].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
                i++;
            }
            sqlcon.Close();

            lblfilmsayisi.Content = ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count;

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: [C# using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx) -- SqlConnection & SqlCommand both implement IDisposable.

Comment: Your code does not show us how "ds" is set.  Check to see if you have some code on your form that is incorrectly repopulating the DataSet pointing to your "ds" variable.

Comment: I am sorry I'm new member and I cant adjust yet this message console

Comment: @DanielA.White: Good luck with your SQL injection endeavours on Winforms apps...